# how to choose sample frequency if there is alias frequency?

Tags: fft, noise

my circuit only need very low frequency of signal and  cannot add anti alias filter in analog domain, so I adopt sample rate frequency hopping  as follow:

1、use FFT to identify if there high value  noise low frequency bin.

---

### 0.1*fs/2<bins <0.2*fs/2

2、use FFT to identify if there high value noise in high frequency bin.

### 0.2*fs/2<bins<fs/2

3、if 1 is low and 2 is high,the sample frequency is good.
there is a problem,if 1 and 2 all is low ,that is noise frequency is alias to the very low interest domain,is there any method for frequency hopping if use fft to avoid this.

### sample frequency can be 100ksps to 300ksps

### noise  frequency can be 100kHz to 10MHz

### my interest frequency  is 100Hz below

Comment: Welcome to our site! I know you state "cannot add anti alias filter in analog domain," but this really looks like case for an analog lowpass filter. Given your low frequency of interest and high noise frequency even a very simple one will do. Maybe just a single bypass capacitor will do the trick.

Comment: this is implement on integrated circuit with many channels like this, so add a capacitor is not feasible